Ошибочный повторный ответ сервера
Пишу свой мессенджер и столкнулся с проблемой в ситуации когда при логине у меня отправляется запрос на проверку пользователя и на создание jwt-токена, но по какой-то причине приходит два ответа от него с задержкой буквально несколько миллисекунд: 1 - правильный, где записан id  и токен авторизованного пользователя, а 2  - ошибочный, которого вообще не должно возникать, который имеет пустой массив данных и код успешности. Программа начинает обрабатывать второй ответ вместо первого и выдает ошибку о некорректности данных от сервера.
Сервер написан на nodejs данные берутся из бд(mongodb, если это на что-то влияет):
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: "./Config.env" });
const writeUri = require('./dbConnection');
const cors = require('cors');
const { generateSalt, hashPassword, validatePassword } = require('./security/crypt');
const { EmailValid } = require("./processingServer/ChekingEmail");
const CreateJWT = require("./security/Create_jwt");
const Dialogs = require("./ChatLogic/SearchAllChats");
const User = require('./modules/Users'); 
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;


app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    methods: ['POST']
}));

// Подключение к MongoDB
mongoose.connect(writeUri, {
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Подключено к MongoDB');
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Ошибка подключения к MongoDB:', error);
});

const isEmailUnique = async (email) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
        return !user;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Ошибка сервера", error)
    }
};

app.post("/api/check-user", async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select({ salt: 1, password: 1, name: 1, _id: 1 }).lean();

        if (!user) {
            console.log("User not found");
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Пользователь не найден' });
        }

        const isValid = validatePassword(password, user.password, user.salt);

        if (!isValid) {
            console.log("Invalid password");
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Неверный логин или пароль' });
        }
        
        const JWT_token = await CreateJWT(user._id, user.name);

        const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, { Jwt: JWT_token }, { new: true }).lean();
        console.log("Updated User:", updatedUser);

        if (!updatedUser) {
            console.log("Error updating token");
            return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Ошибка обновления токена' });
        }

        console.log("Sending success response");
        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: 'Добро пожаловать!',
            token: JWT_token,
            id: updatedUser._id.toString(),
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Ошибка при проверке пользователя:', error);
        return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Ошибка сервера' });
    }
});

app.post("/api/create-user", async (req, res) =>{
    const {UserName, email, password} = req.body;

    // Проверка валидности email
    if (!EmailValid(email)) {
        return res.status(402).json({ success: false, message: 'Некорректный формат электронной почты' });
    }
    else
        isEmailUnique();

    // Проверка уникальности email
    if (!(await isEmailUnique(email))) {
        return res.status(403).json({ success: false, message: 'Электронная почта уже используется' });
    }

    const CreateSalt = generateSalt();
    const HashedPaswd = hashPassword(password, CreateSalt);

    const newUser = new User({
        name: UserName,
        email: email,
        password: HashedPaswd,
        salt: CreateSalt,
        Jwt: ''
    })

    try {
        await newUser.save();
        console.log("Пользователь успешно создан!")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Произошла ошибка создания пользователя", error)
    }
})

app.post('/api/SearchAllUnikChats', async (req, res) => {
    const { JwtToken, Userid } = req.body;
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ Jwt: JwtToken }).lean();
        if (user) {
            const FindDialogs = await Dialogs(Userid);
            res.status(200).json({ success: true, FindDialogs });
        } else {
            res.status(403).json({ success: false, message: 'Ошибка в токене' });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Ошибка поиска диалогов:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Ошибка сервера' });
    }
});



// Запуск сервера
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Сервер запущен на http://127.0.0.1:${PORT}`);
});

module.exports = {User};

И код клиентской части, в которой происходит вся эта тема(React Native expo):
const handleMessage = useCallback(async (event) => {
        try {
            console.log("Raw event data:", event.data); // Логируем сырые данные
            const response = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log("Parsed response:", response); // Логируем разобранные данные
            if (response.success) {
                if (response.token && response.id) {  // Проверяем наличие token и id
                    console.log(response);
                    try {
                        await AsyncStorage.setItem('JwtToken', response.token);
                        await AsyncStorage.setItem('_id', response.id);
                        Alert.alert("Успешно", response.message);
                        navigation.replace("MainMenu");
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        Alert.alert("Не сохранило данные.");
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Server res: ", response);
                    Alert.alert("Ошибка", "Некорректные данные с сервера.");
                }
            } else {
                Alert.alert("Ошибка", response.message);
                if (response.message === "неверный логин или пароль" && formikRef.current) {
                    formikRef.current.setFieldValue('password', ''); // Очищаем поле пароля
                }
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Ошибка при разборе сообщения:', e, event.data);
        }
    }, [navigation]);    

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (socket) {
            socket.addEventListener('message', handleMessage);
            return () => {
                socket.removeEventListener('message', handleMessage);
            };
        }
    }, [socket, handleMessage]);

Есть также промежуточный сервер на WebSoket, но вроде дело не в нем, но прикреплю на всякий случай, если проблема все-таки в нем:
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';
import axios from 'axios';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import messageHandlers from './processingMessages/GeneralProc.js';

dotenv.config({ path: "./Config.env" });

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
const server = http.createServer(app);
// Создаем WebSocket сервер
const wss = new WebSocketServer({ server });

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    console.log('Новое WebSocket-соединение установлено');

    ws.on('message', async (message) => {
        try {
            const data = JSON.parse(message.toString());
            const hendler = messageHandlers[data.type];
            if(hendler)
                hendler(ws, data);
            else
                ws.send(JSON.stringify({success: false, message: "Тип запроса не найден"}));
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Ошибка при обработке данных:', error.message);
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: 'Ошибка при обработке данных' }));
        }
    });

    ws.on('close', (code, reason) => {
        console.log(`Соединение закрыто. Код: ${code}, Причина: ${reason}`);
    });
});
// Запуск сервера
server.listen(PORT, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Ошибка при запуске сервера:', err);
    } else {
        console.log(`Сервер запущен на http://localhost:${PORT}`);
    }
});

export default server;

Сам логин в websoket
import axios from 'axios';

async function LoginCheck(ws, { email, password }) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(process.env.URL_CHECK_USER, { email, password });
        ws.send(JSON.stringify(response.data)); // Успешный ответ клиенту
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Ошибка при отправке запроса:', err.message);
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: 'Неверный логин или пароль' }));
    }
}

export default LoginCheck;

messageHandlers - просто функция определяющая тип запроса и ничего более
тут немного пояснения что я вижу в консоли приложения, когда приходит ответ от сервера


Как вы определили, что приходит 2 ответа? Сколько запросов идет с клиента? Сколько раз функция отрабатывает на сервере? Возможно есть "побочное действие" на стороне реакта, что приводит к запуску какой то функции, при еще не обновленном состоянии?

@SwaD я вывожу в консоль себе приходящие ответы от сервера, дополнил свой пост скриншотом с небольшим пояснением. Что насчет доп запросов от реакт приложения, то это  навряд ли, так как он бы обрабатывал и тот и другой запрос, а он обрабатывает только 2

Смотрите вкладку "сеть" браузера. Там будет видно, сколько реальных и каких запросов уходит с клиента и сколько приходит. То что в консоли, это уже последствия. И не понятно, зачем вам useCallback для обработчика ответа

@SwaD использую useCallback для мемоизирования функции, чтобы 100% на рендере еще одного запроса не произошло. Но в общем я щас посидел и нашел проблему. Пошел решать от малого к большему и нашел в чем был камень преткновения. При передача запроса, каким-то образом сервер давал двойной ответ(скорее всего из-за кривого кода). Спасибо, что посоветовали посмотреть это, так как я думал, что все-таки пробелма в websokete, который как раз и передает запросы на сервер
